# crystal reports Integer division

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hi I am trying for a integer output for float/float

If I am using integer division I think that is rounding the float before division and giving a result which I am not expecting.
Example:

```
24.2/4.5=5.33
```

here I want to see a result  of 5
integer division giving me 4 for above operation

Can some one please help me how can I get the result I am looking for
Thanks

Comment: Got it, Truncate(24.2/4.5) giving me 5

Answer (score 2):

Got it, Truncate(24.2/4.5) giving me 5